# Use existing column names

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I have a Windows Forms application (PC installable) in C#. I've created a DataGridView with the form designer, and am binding a DataTable to it at run-time. The DataTable is populated by a SQL call.

The DataGridView columns have been given specific HeaderText values at design-time that I want to keep. For example, "Confirmation Number" is one of my column headings. In addition, the Name property of each column has been set to match the value returned by the SQL call. So, for example, my "Confirmation Number" column has a Name property of "vchReturnReceipt" because that is the column name returned by SQL.

The data is coming back from SQL, it is getting bound to the DataViewGrid, and it is displaying, BUT the grid is creating new columns for all the returned data rather than using the pre-defined columns (the pre-defined columns are still there, and new columns are added to the right of them). For example, a new column called "vchReturnReceipt" is created, holding the value that I want to show up in the "Confirmation Number" column.

How do I display data in the existing columns, and prevent the new columns from showing up?

Answer (score 0):

Before binding data do two things:

define for predefined columns a `.DataPropertyName` property with Database columns name
(in Designer open "Edit Columns" from Datagridview optons)

then set `.AutoGenerateColumns = False`

After this binding data will based on `.DatPropertyName` columns names